# Is it possible to fix the mean/var arg in tfpl.IndependentNormal?

Tags: python, tensorflow-probability

I wrote a standard probabilistic neural network in Python with the last layer being tfp.layers.IndependentNormal giving me a normal distribution. However, I just want to train the mean of said distribution, leaving the variance fixed.

Has anyone tried anything similar or has an idea how to do that?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
model = Sequential([
    ...
    tfpl.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc = t, scale = 0.5)))
])
```

Here you need to set `scale` into a constant value to keep it fixed.